# Regular Expression with the Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

> SELECT a.[PREMISES],a.[Class] FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a;

Above query returns :

[image]

Can you tell me how to remove `210,` and `211,` from the query column `a.[Class]` ?

**Note :** I just gave an example.I need to have a generic solution which will apply for all the rows of that `a.[Class]` column.

**Note 2 :** Format of the `Class` column is like this.`numeric` then `,` after that `string`.I need to remove first 2 parts.Need to keep only the `string` part.

Comment: `SELECT a.[PREMISES], SUBSTRING(a.[Class], 5, 100) FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a;`

Comment: is your class column have specific format data??

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes,It's like this `numeric` then `,` after that `string`

Comment: ok then you can refer Sujeet Ans, this may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use a regular expression here.  You could try using [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
SELECT  a.[PREMISES],
        REPLACE(REPLACE(a.[Class],'210, ',''),'211, ','') as [Class] 
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a;
```

To remove all before first `,`:

```
SELECT  a.[PREMISES],
        LTRIM(RIGHT(NULLIF(a.[Class],''),LEN(a.[Class])-CHARINDEX(',',a.[Class]))) as [Class]
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a;
```

This query, for that data

```
PREMISES            Class
Victoria Ln         210, Single Family (no style specified)
West 10th Street    211, Ranch, Single Family
East 2nd Street     Single Family
```

Will give you this output:

```
PREMISES            Class
Victoria Ln         Single Family (no style specified)
West 10th Street    Ranch, Single Family
East 2nd Street     Single Family
```

Comment: This won't work.I just gave an example.I need to have generic solution which will apply for all the rows.Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Done that.

Comment: You need to remove first 5 symbols from `[Class]` row? Or there are some cases?

Comment: It's like this `numeric` then `,` after that `string`.I need to remove first 2 parts.Need to keep only the `string` part.

Comment: Please, check edit to my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Can you tell me will this remove the leading spaces of the `string` too ?

Comment: I specify `', '` so yes will remove them, if you specify `','` in `REPLACE` statement then you will need to `LTRIM` output.

Comment: Above query gives this error.Can you tell me why ? `Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.`

Comment: That mean there are `''` empty values in `[Class]` column. I add workaround to this query

Comment: Yes,Now it is working.Thanks.Do you know why `TRIM` is not working with the `SQL server 2014 express` ?

Comment: As I remember there are `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to cut off spaces from left and right respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to return the result starting from `,`.

```
SELECT  a.[PREMISES],
        SUBSTRING(a.[Class], CHARINDEX(',',a.[Class]) + 1, LEN(a.[Class])) as [Class] 
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all numeric characters from a string.

```
SELECT a.[PREMISES],
    SUBSTRING(a[Class], PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', a.[Class]), LEN(a.[Class])) 
  FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fun_Refiner ( @val VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN
            IF PATINDEX('[0-9]%', @val) > 0 OR SUBSTRING(@val, 1, 1) = ','
                SET @val = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@val,SUBSTRING(@val,PATINDEX('[0-9,]%',@val), 1), '')));
            ELSE
                BREAK;
        END;
      RETURN @val
END;
```

And just call it like this:

```
SELECT a.[Class], dbo.Fun_Refiner(a.[Class]) FROM YourTable AS a
```